# Check the value exists in List using C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, list, linq

I have List as mentioned below. Now When I am going to add new string value into this list, My method **GetNewCopiedValue** has to check the new text value into the list **lstNames**.If the name does not exist in the list it should return the value as it is. If the new string value is exist already in the list, it has to return the string with respective index number as like EC(1).For example, If I am sending EC(1) again to the list, the method has to check the value in the list and It should return EC(3) since EC(1) is exist already in the list, the method has to check the similar values and it should return the value with next index number which is not there in the list.

```
Main()
{
    List<string> lstNames=new List<string>{"Ecard","EC","EC(1)","EC(2)","NCard(1)"};
    var copiedValue= GetNewCopiedValue(lstNames,EC(2));
    Console.WriteLine("Copied Text is :"+copiedValue);
}
public static string GetNewCopiedValue(List<string> lstNames,string sourceLabel)
{
  label = sourceLabel;         

        if (lstNames.Any(i => i.Equals(sourceLabel)))
        {
            var labelSubstring = sourceLabel.Substring(0, sourceLabel.Length - 2);
            var sameNameList = lstNames.Where(i => i.Contains(labelSubstring)).ToList();
            int count = sameNameList.Count+1;
            label = labelSubstring + count + ")";
            while (lstNames.Any(i => i.Equals(label)))
            {
                var indexLabel = sourceLabel.Substring(sourceLabel.Length-2,1);
                var maxIndex = sameNameList.Max(i =>int.Parse( i.Substring(sourceLabel.Length - 2, 1)));
                int labelCount = maxIndex + 1;
                label = labelSubstring + labelCount + ")";                   
            }
        }
        return label;
}
```

Actual Input:
EC(2)

Expected output:
EC(3)

I have tried with some logic but it was not working with all input strings. It worked for few cases only.
Please help me on this.

Comment: Please include an [mcve]... something that anyone could copy/paste into an empty c# file and execute. Otherwise we have to guess as to what the code not shown might be doing. If you are not sure if it is an [mcve] form then use http://dotnetfiddle.net/, if it can run there then it is good.

Comment: What should the values be if your list is empty and you attempt to insert `a` four times?

Comment: Also include actual input, expected output, and actual output. This allows us to understand the behavior of the code shown as well as what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: It should be like : a , a (1) , a(2) , a(3)

Comment: @Igor: EdIted the question

Comment: Gotta love it when the admins don't even give a person a chance to improve the question before closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/dFrzhA

```
    public static void Main() {
        List<string> lstNames= new List<string>{"Ecard","EC","EC(1)","EC(2)","NCard(1)"};
        var copiedValue= GetNewCopiedValue(lstNames, "EC(1)");
        Console.WriteLine("Copied Text is :" + copiedValue);
    }
    
    public static string GetNewCopiedValue(List<string> lstNames, string ValueToCopyInList) {
        string newName;

        if (!lstNames.Contains(ValueToCopyInList)) {
            newName = ValueToCopyInList;
        } else {
            int? suffix = ParseSuffix(ValueToCopyInList);
            string baseName = suffix == null ? ValueToCopyInList : ValueToCopyInList.Substring(0, ValueToCopyInList.LastIndexOf('('));
            suffix = suffix ?? 1;
            newName = baseName + "(" + suffix + ")";
            
            while (lstNames.Contains(newName)) {
                suffix++;
                newName = baseName + "(" + suffix + ")";
            }
        }
        
        lstNames.Add(newName);
        return newName;
    }
    
    public static int? ParseSuffix(string value) {
        int output;
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return null;
        if (!value.EndsWith(")")) {
            return null;
        }
        
        var idxStart = value.LastIndexOf('(');
        var strResult = value.Substring(idxStart + 1, value.Length - (idxStart + 2));
        
        if (int.TryParse(strResult, out output))
            return output;
        
        return null;
    }
```